# Xamarin Forms WebView open external link

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a webview inside my application and when an external link is clicked (that in normal browser is open in a new tab), I can't then go back to my website.

It is possible when a new tab is open to have the menu closed that tab like Gmail do ?

[image]

The objective is that, whenever a link is clicked, the user would have the choice to choose which option to view the content with, e.g. Clicking a link would suggest open youtube app or google chrome. The purpose is to appear the google chrome option

Or what suggestions do you have to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 6):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have the option to select how to open the web link - inside your app, or within another app's (browser) context.

If this is correct, then you can use [**Xamarin.Essentials: Browser**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android) functionality.

```cs
public async Task OpenBrowser(Uri uri)
{
    await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
}
```

Here the important property is the `BrowserLaunchMode` flag, which you can learn more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.browserlaunchmode?view=xamarin-essentials)

Basically, you have 2 options - `External` & `SystemPreferred`.

1. The first one is clear, I think - it will open the link in an external browser.
2. The second options takes advantage of Android's [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) & for iOS - [SFSafariViewController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/safariservices.sfsafariviewcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

P.S. You can also customise the `PreferredToolbarColor`, `TitleMode`, etc.

Edit: Based from your feedback in the comments, you want to control how to open href links from your website.

If I understood correctly, you want the first time that you open your site, to not have the nav bar at the top, and after that to have it. Unfortunately, this is not possible.

You can have the opposite behaviour achieved - the first time that you open a website, to have the nav bar and if the user clicks on any link, to open it externally (inside a browser). You have 2 options for this:

1. To do it from your website - change the `a` tag's target to be `_blank` like [this](https://html.com/attributes/a-target/);
2. To do it from your mobile app - create a [Custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for the WebView. In the Android project's renderer implementation, change the `Control`'s `WebViewClient` like so:

```cs
    public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, request.Url);
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.StartActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't express my doubt correctly. What I want to achieve is that by clicking in the hypertext link that is displayed on the webview, to be handled by an application (chrome or default browser) in order to be have the outcome of the picture displayed above (the top part of the picture, acting as a temporary tab)

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that using `BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred`. When you open the link with Essentials and set this flag, it will be opened "internally", meaning that you will still be inside your app, and you will see the nav bar as you want.

Comment: That works, but what I wanted is the first website not have that nav bar, but all the external links in that website to open in some page with that that nav bar. I don't know if it is possible to do do on the application or if I need to do something in the website.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. But abou your solutions, the first one I've already tried and it really opens in new "tab" but there's no way to go back once thats' open. The second solution I didn't get it to work. I created a Renderer in WebView and all works fine, but never steps in that method.

Comment: Please try to use `FormsWebViewClient` to replace the `WebViewClient`, then make a test.