# Need to implement SetSupportMultipleWindows on Xamarin Webview app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

I need to set SetSupportMultipleWindows to false in Xamarin WebView, because I'm unable to load pages with other domain name. I'm newbie in C# and Xamarin, so I used YT tutorials to build my WebView and Splashscreen. I tried multiple options from web, but can't solve it by my own. Only thing i need to change is this setting.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TruckAndTrailer.MainPage">

    
    <WebView x:Name="webview"></WebView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TruckAndTrailer
{

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            webview.Source = "https://www.google.com/";
            webview.Navigated += (o, s) =>{
            webview.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('mk-footer').style.display = 'none';");
            };
            
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            if (webview.CanGoBack)
            {
                webview.GoBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TruckAndTrailer.Droid
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());        
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

If anything more is needed I will provide it.

Comment: That property should default to false if its not being set by Xamarin. What are you expecting that property to do that it is not doing now? In order to set that property you will need to create a customer renderer of WebView in your Android project. Use [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-each-platform) and scroll down to the Android section. Its not a simple task with WebView so there might be an easier way without using a custom renderer.

Comment: @hvaughan3 I will try to work with it one more time, but I couldn't really implement this. I was reading some GitHub issues posts with the same problem and the solution for Xamarin is to set this setting to false. I'm expecting this to make me able to open website from other domain in my webview. On mobile version of my website if I click the banner for example it opens new tab with another website. I also have embed link for online magazine which opens in new tab on phone. Unfortunately in my webview those do nothing, it clicks but don't redirect or prompt to open browser.

Comment: You can check the updated part in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set this setting, you can use the custom renderer as
hvaughan3 said.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(ProjectTest.Droid.MyWebViewRender))]
namespace ProjectTest.Droid
{
public class MyWebViewRender : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRenderer
{
    public MyWebViewRender(Context context) : base(context) { }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {  
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control != null)
        {
           Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Create a render in your android part with the code above.

**Update**

Or you want to open some special link in the browser you can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704452/how-can-i-modify-a-webview-in-xamarin-forms-to-open-links-in-a-browser-on-the-de) which added the navigating event to the webview to do that.

In addtion, you can also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610182/xamarin-forms-webview-open-external-link) which open external link by using the costom renderer and override the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.

Comment: Thank you so much. After your instruction and pointing which file need rebuild i was able to implement everything i wanted and even some more.

Comment: This definitely fixes the issue for me. window.location works when exporting the custom renderer.